# Objective C Terminology Help

Tags: objective-c

So I know a bit of C, trying to jump into ObjC for Max apps. Trying to figure out the terms and just needed a guru to humor me.

So an *object* could be thought of as a house that holds operations and data together.

But there may be many different objects of the same kind, called an *instance*. This could be thought of as a trailer park (manufactured home community) with a bunch of object homes. Not sure how to give an example of a *type* however.

Following same example, the *methods* would be the way the data in the house is manipulated?

Trying to figure these definitions out in a very simple example for my brain :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds more like you need some education on Object Oriented Programming in general rather than Objective-C specifically.  Do some googling for general OOP references.  Here's some basics referring to your specific question:

Object:  A general term for a combination of data and related operations
Class: A specific definition of an object, i.e. NSController
Instance: A specific object created from a Class definition

So, I could have an object Controller1, that is an instance of the NSController class.  This could be referred to as an "NSController object" or an instance of "NSController".

Comment: @phoebus @Nick, yeah looks like I need to read up on OOP a little first. Hopefully my basic knowledge of C will help or no?

Comment: Your C knowledge will help with syntactical examples, and understanding the concept of a C struct will help you get the idea of a class encapsulating data and methods.

Answer (score 0):

Stop using these analogies, just start playing around with tutorials and the code, you will get the hang of what everything does in no time.

In my words I would call methods a collective of instructions that you can call on with the given method name.

But really, just start writing code, the rest will come :) (no copy pasting!!)

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking has little to do with Objective-C specifically, and everything to do with [Object-Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).  Read up on that before diving into the new language!

Answer (score 0):

I know this topic is quite old, but I thought I'd try and help out in case anyone is coming here looking for answers.

**Object**

> Blueprint for a house. It has the plans for building a house, and it will even supply the contractors to build the house for you, but it is not the house.

**Instance**

> This is a house. It also keeps track of all of the characteristics of the house, and as a result it can be introspective. IE: You can ask the house how many rooms it has, what its dimensions are &etc.

**Method**

> Most every object will define methods. Methods do stuff. Following the house analogy, a method would be the mechanism that would grab the dimensions for you and print them out, or it could be something that would modify the state of the house. IE: call a plumber to fix a leaky pipe on the house.